# How GWT applications are deployed in tomcat or jetty

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT framework How GWT based application's are deployed in tomcat or jetty or Is there any other way to host or distribute the GWT based applications?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the application and package it as WAR (web application archive) (like any other web application) and then deploy it to the application server like tomcat.

An `Ant` target could look like this:

```
    <target name="buildwar">
        <war basedir="war" destfile="Project.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/gwt-servlet.jar" />
            <include name="**/classes/**" />
        </webinf>
        </war>
    </target>
```

For `maven`, you can use [Maven GWT Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/war-folder.html)

Answer (score 0):

### ***Deploying to Java EE Web Server***

You can follow the examples provided by gwt team code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples

The samples provide for setting up a war project
1) ant build example
2) maven build example .

Once a war file is created it can be deployed into jetty,tomcat,resin, websphere, etc

### ***Deploying to cloud***

Also apart from deploying into Jetty/Tomcat you can also deploy to **Google APP Engine Server** . Reference GAE GWT Guide - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.